# What is the best way to implement an actor chain in Akka?

Tags: java, akka

I'm trying to use Akka to process a polled REST call. Currently I have the actor reschedule itself until the correct response is retrieved. This works but the final result is never returned. How should I do this and if this isn't the right way how should it be done?

I am using Java so please can any code be in Java not Scala.

Start the actor chain:

```
        Props props = Props.create(SpringExtProvider.get(myActorSystem).props("RefreshAccountActor").actorClass(), aggregatorSourceSessionManager.getSession().getSessionToken(), userSession.getSessionToken());
        ActorRef ref = myActorSystem.actorOf(props, "ref");
        FiniteDuration duration = FiniteDuration.create(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Future<Object> siteAccountInfoFuture = Patterns.ask(ref, AccountMessages.SiteRefreshInfoMessage.toSiteRefreshInfoMessage(siteAccountInfo.getSiteRefreshInfo()), Timeout.durationToTimeout(duration));
        siteAccountInfoFuture.onSuccess(new OnSuccess<Object>() {
            public void onSuccess(Object result) {
                // Update DB?
                logger.info("Refresh successful");
                //Do something with result
            }
        }, myActorSystem.dispatcher());
```

RefreshAccountActor:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    if (message instanceof SiteRefreshInfoMessage) {
        SiteRefreshInfoMessage siteRefreshInfoMessage = (SiteRefreshInfoMessage) message;
        if (!siteRefreshInfoMessage.getStatus().equals("COMPLETE")) {
            // siteRefreshRetry is populated here
            // Schedule another attempt
            getContext().system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(
                            Duration.create(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                            getSelf(), siteRefreshRetry,
                            getContext().dispatcher(), null),
                        getSelf();
        } else {
            // Refresh done
            // This doesn't seem to get through
            getSender().tell(siteRefreshInfoMessage, getSelf());
        }
    } else if (message instanceof SiteRefreshRetry) {
        // Do REST call here to populate siteRefreshInfoMessage
        // Now process message
        onReceive(siteRefreshInfoMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two things wrong with your code.  One, you should never call `onReceive` directly.  That will be called by the actor framework after dequeuing a message from the mailbox.  If two pieces of handling need to share logic, create a separate method that both can call.  Second, you lose the `sender` of the original message when you are scheduling your task.  That last arg, that you are setting to `null` should instead be set to `getSender()`.  If you do that, then the right `sender` will be present on the `SiteRefreshRetry` message handling logic and can then be responded to.

Comment: I've made those changes but now when the cycle is complete and the ```tell()``` is invoked the whole thing goes into an infinite loop processing the same message over and over.

Comment: My mistake  - I made a typo and used getSelf() instead of getSender()! Works now, thanks